# Running docker command with nest.js

Tags: typescript, docker, cypress, nestjs

My question is I have back-end nest.js code and there is running cypress.js docker container. I have also front-end.(website)

When user clicks from website, I want to run docker command and run test from container. How can I communicate with docker container to make container run itself. I want to trigger container so I can use with command.

I can execute command like "docker container exec some related test" but I want it to be performed automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [node-docker-api](https://github.com/AgustinCB/docker-api):

```
container.exec.create({
    AttachStdout: true,
    AttachStderr: true,
    Cmd: [ 'some', 'related', 'test' ]
})
```

or do something as simple as:

```
const {exec}  = require('shelljs')

function handler() {
    const child = exec(`docker container exec some related test`)
    console.log(child.stdout)
}
```